# Java 8 App Engine Running in Eclipse, @WebServlet not working

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am running App Engine Standard inside of Eclipse

Two of my "servlets" work using "@WebServlet" but 3 do not.
This works:

```
com.ifmrestoration.corrigo.CustomFieldServlet
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@WebServlet(name = "CFAAppEngine", urlPatterns = { "/customfields" })
public class CustomFieldServlet extends HttpServlet {
```

This doesn't:

```
com.ifmrestoration.webscraper.ImageDownloaderServlet
@WebServlet(name = "DownloadServer", urlPatterns = { "/corrigoimagesdownload" })
public class ImageDownloaderServlet extends HttpServlet {
```

Here is the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need both the [web.xml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/webxml) and [appengine-web.xml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref) if you are using GAE standard with Java as they are used to describe how your app is configured.
You can see the documents for details on which configuration setting you need for your application.